# How to fix Incorrect syntax error in CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

When I do this query, it gives me the error "incorrect syntax near t1".

The query works if it's not within the CTE. How can you do this in CTE?

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
    FROM ticket t1
    WHERE...

    UNION

    SELECT t1.id
    FROM ticket t1
        ,ticket t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.matching_ticket_id
        AND t2.id NOT IN (
            SELECT ticket_id
            FROM aa
                ,pa
            WHERE aa.id = pa.account_id
            )
    ) t1 --> incorrect syntax near t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
    FROM ticket t1
    WHERE t1.id NOT IN (
            SELECT ticket_id
            FROM aa
                ,pa
            WHERE aa.id = pa.account_id
            )
    ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id --> incorrect syntax near t2

UNION

(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
    FROM cd_ticket t1
    WHERE...

    UNION

    SELECT t1.id
    FROM cd_ticket t1
        ,cd_ticket t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.matching_ticket_id
        AND t2.id NOT IN (
            SELECT ticket_id
            FROM cd_aa
                ,cd_pa
            WHERE aa.id = pa.account_id
            )
    ) t1 --> incorrect syntax near t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
    FROM cd_ticket t1
    WHERE t1.id NOT IN (
            SELECT ticket_id
            FROM cd_aa
                ,cd_pa
            WHERE aa.id = pa.account_id
            )
    ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id --> incorrect syntax near t2
```

Comment: Explain the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: If you are running the actual query then  WHERE... will give an error.

Comment: Here is an improved version of your query and the best approach of solving this issue is to go part by part by commenting some of the query at the bottom - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1be9dc9294cd85dd0a9869457fc4e79

Comment: Stop aliasing everything as just t1 and t2! It's fine to use them as table aliases inside your CTEs and expressions, but you'll run into problems reusing them as outer aliases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to JOIN directly to the CTE; that is not how they work.

If you want join to a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS ( somequery )
SELECT stuff
FROM aTable AS a INNER JOIN CTE AS c ON a.somefield = CTE.somefield
```

If you want the CTE to represent two joined subqueries, they need to be within the CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT stuff 
   FROM (
      subquery1
   ) AS q1 
   INNER JOIN (
      subquery2
   ) AS q2 ON ....)
SELECT stuff 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "table expressions" with "common table expressions", so you are mixing the syntax of both of them, into something that is not a legal SQL statement.

See the difference, and make up your mind on which one to use:

**Table Expression** (aka "derived table", "inline view", etc.):

```
select *
from (
  select ... -- my complex select #1 here
) a
join (
  select ... -- my complex select #2 here
) b on a.column_a = b.column_b
```

Table expressions appear in the `FROM` clause and they are named just after the closing parenthesis. The `SELECT` statement is written at the beginning.

**Common Table Expression** (CTE):

```
with 
a as (
  select ... -- my complex select #1 here
),
b as (
  select ... -- my complex select #2 here
)
select * from a join b on a.column_a = b.column_b
```

As you see Common Table Expressions are declared first, the aliases are defined before the open parenthesis, and they are separated by commas. The main `SELECT` is written at the end. One advantage of CTEs is that you can use the common table expressions many times, in subsequent CTEs, and in the final/main `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a CTE but then go straight to a union which requires a preceding `SELECT`.

Your second query has a unncessary trailing bracket with a `t1` alias but I assume you want that as a derived table so It will need an opening bracket before the `SELECT`

You probably want something like this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select distinct t1.id from ticket t1 where ...
)
SELECT id FROM CTE
union
SELECT * FROM 
(
select  t1.id
from    ticket t1,
        ticket t2
where   t1.id = t2.matching_ticket_id and
        t2.id not in  ( select  ticket_id from aa, pa where aa.id = pa.account_id )
)  t1

join
```

etc......

Also, as a side, you should steer away from the old JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT ticket_id
FROM   aa, pa
WHERE  aa.id = pa.account_id
```

and re-write as

```
SELECT ticket_id
FROM   aa
       JOIN oa
          ON aa.id=pa.account_id
```